# Python parsing Nested Ordereddict

Tags: python, parsing, ordereddictionary

I have a nested ordered dictionary field with the following value:

```
OrderedDict
([
 ('activateable', False),
 ('fields', 
    [OrderedDict ([ ('autoNumber', False),  ('name', ‘col_1’),  (‘amount’, ‘10’)]),
    [OrderedDict ([ ('autoNumber', False),  ('name', ‘col_2’),  (‘amount’, ‘10’)])
 )
 ('pin', False)
])
```

I want to pass the value col_1, col_2 and get the corresponding amount value.
I’ve tried parsing by regular for loops and other iterations but couldn’t get it to the second level.
Can you please suggest a method on how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing an `OrderedDict`"? Did you convert that structure into a string and you are trying to convert it back? Or do you want to simply *access* the fields `col_1` etc? In this second case just use: `d['fields'][i]['name']` for the `col_1` value in the first dictionary etc.

Comment: Any example to make sure that we understand your question ?

Comment: Could you check the posted code, because parens don't match.

Comment: Are sure you need the "Ordered" part in OrderedDict for this example?

Comment: I think all that Mahesh wants is the equivalent of `SELECT amount FROM fields WHERE name = ?`

Comment: What Joeln said is correct. The data comes from Salesforce api and it is in ordered dict format. I have to get the amount value from a nested ordered dict value if I pass the value for name field. I'm not in front of comp at the moment to check Bakiru 's code, I'll reply back as soon as I get to computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to access the `amount` value of the sub-dictionary that has `name` equal to some specified value (e.g. `"col_1"`). There's no direct way to find that without a loop, as you're searching for a value, not a key, but the code required shouldn't need to be terribly complicated:

```
for field in top_level_dict["fields"]:
    if field["name"] = "col_1":
        print(field["amount"])
        break
```

This prints the first match it finds (you can do whatever you want, rather than printing, that just seemed easiest for example code). If there is more than one sub-dict that can match and you want to print the `"amount"` values from all of them, you can take out the `break` statement.

If you have more than one value to search for, you might want to convert your data structure to something that can do more efficient lookups. For instance, here's some basic code to make a new dictionary that maps from your `name` values to the `amount` values (I'm assuming that all names are unique):

```
# set up a better mapping
name_amount_dict = {field["name"]: field["amount"] for field in top_level_dict["fields"]}

# use it to look up a value we want
print(name_amount_dict["col_1"])
```

Comment: you should accept this answer to thank Blckknght for his work in helping you.